# Java- Concurrency & Interleaving

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So our task is to find an interleaving which results in a result < 10.
Right now im having trouble finding said interleaving.

My first idea was something like:

-doing the for-loop from the first thread till the last iteration
-then the threads start to interleave so sum gets reset to 1
-this will result in sum = 10

The second idea was :

-let them interleave from the beginning 
-each time both countedsofar from both threads will be upgraded and afterwards the sum 
-this will also result in sum = 10

Now i have no clue how it is possible to get sum below 10.
I added the code , any help would be appreciated.

```
public class ConcurrentCounter {

private static int sum = 0;
private static final int max = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable count = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int countedSoFar;

            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                countedSoFar = sum;

                //helps to see more interleavings
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sum = countedSoFar + 1;
            }
        }
    };


    Thread countFirst = new Thread(count);
    Thread countSecond = new Thread(count);

    countFirst.start();
    countSecond.start();

    //wait until both threads are finished
    countFirst.join();
    countSecond.join();

    System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```

This is my first post on here so I hope it fits all the criteria, and if not I'm open for any kind of critic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you can get `sum = 2` if I am not mistaken - let's assume following scenario:

1. both threads start with `countedSoFar = 0`.
2. first thread will execute 9 rounds changing `sum` to 9
3. second thread finish first round changing `sum` back to `countedSoFar (=0) + 1 = 1`.
4. first threads starts the last round setting `countedSoFar = sum = 1`.
5. second threads finish all its round (value `sum` is not interesting)
6. first round finish with setting `sum = 1+1`

Comment: Thank you very much, I have somehow thought that countedSoFar  is global . Thank you for the quick answer.